# Java based task processing server

Tags: java, beanstalkd

Looking for a base framework for a small, lightweight server that can efficiently pull jobs/messages off of something like beanstalk or SQS and process them.

Octobot (https://github.com/cscotta/octobot) looks good, but no one seems to be contributing to it recently.  Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

As awful as it might seem, you might want to consider running your stuff inside Tomcat. You can pack your application as a war, have nice automated deployment options and it's quite easy to tie into the lifecycle of a webapp. Plus, if you need a management frontend, you are halfway there (although JMX might be better suited).

You can also look at Spring Batch/Spring Integration, which might provide components you can use.